# How to edit the schema of a SparkDataFrame?

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I have a SparkDataFrame on which I want to apply some function using dapply() and add a new column.

dapply in SparkR expect the schema which will match to the output of the called function.
e.g.,

```
#Creating SparkDataFrame

sdf<-as.DataFrame(iris)

#Initiating Schema

schm<-structType(structField("Sepal_Length", "double"),structField("Sepal_Width", "double"),structField("Petal_Length","double"),structField("Petal_Width","double"),structField("Species","string"),structField("Specie_new","string"))

#dapply code
sdf2<-dapply(sdf,function(y)
  {
    y$Specie_new<-substr(y$Specie,nchar(y$Species)-1,nchar(y$Species))
return(y)
},schm)
```

Is there any better way to do the same? I mean if I have 100 columns then this won't be a feasible option, what should I do in these cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arguably a better way is to avoid `dapply` for simple cases like this one. You could easily use simple regexp to achieve the same result:

```
regexp_extract(df$Species, "^.*(.{2})$", 1)
```

or a combination of Spark SQL functions (`SparkR::substr`, `SparkR::length`).

Still, you can easily reuse existing schema to create na ew one. Assuming you want to add new field `foo`:

```
foo <- structField("foo", "string")
```

just extract fields of an existing one and combine them:

```
do.call(structType, c(schema(df)$fields(), list(foo)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a bit late, but adding to the answer of zero323, as of Spark v2.2.0:

```
#Initiating Schema    
added_schm <- structType(structField("Specie_new","string"))
schm <- do.call(structType, append(schema(sdf)$fields(), added_schm$fields()))
```